# JSON send not being accepted by server API

Tags: javascript, json, object

I am trying to send a JSON object to a web api, but am having a bit of trouble. Its supposed to take value from an input, check the response first, and if the response is correct, send the data. Here is my JS code:

```
var form = document.getElementById("inputForm"), master = {}, xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); //global variables used for checking different parts of the process
form.onsubmit = function (e) {
// stop the regular form submission
    e.preventDefault();

// collect the form data while iterating over the inputs
    var data = {};
    for (var i = 0, ii = form.length; i < ii; ++i) {
    var input = form[i];
    if (input.name) {
        data[input.name] = input.value;
    }
    master.data = data;
}
// construct an HTTP request
function get(url, callback) {
xhr.open("GET", url);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        var type = xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Type");
        if (type.indexOf("xml") !== -1 && xhr.responseXML)
            callback(xhr.responseXML);
        else if (type === "application/json")
            callback(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
        else
            callback(xhr.responseText);
    }
};
// send the collected data as JSON
console.log(JSON.stringify(master));
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(master));
}
get("http://example.com:12321/data");
};
```

However, when sending it, I get a HTTP 500 error in the console, and the output in the server itself says:

```
Processing request on /data
Caught error: <unspecified file>(1): expected object or array
```

And here is the result of the console.log:

```
{"data":{"val":"2"}}
```

I thought I was sending the data correctly, but it isnt recognizing it. The example they gave was of a .json file and that works fine, but my stringified JSON isnt working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You have to run json decode on server to create on array/object from the encoded string. By php the json_decode function does that.

Comment: @inf3rno is there a way to send that through with the XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: nope. you encode the data on client side, send it to the server as a json serialized string, after that you decode that on the server ... the 500 error means internal server error, so the problem is with the server side code, not the client side... check your error logs on server! btw if you send data with XHR a POST method would be better. the GET is for displaying data...